# Chat room access control: searching by user name can give unexpected results

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, chat, user-search

[image]

- Searching by **user name** searches *more* than just the user name (Patrick has the word 'waffles' in his about section) -- is this desirable behaviour?
- Even if a user matches the search criteria on a field other than user name, I think those matches should appear at the *end* of the results. Ideally, ordering would be, for each field starting with user name: (a) exact match, (b) starts with criteria, (c) contains criteria -- meaning the search results I've shown above would be returned in the opposite order, which, in this case at least, would have been more useful.
- There are actually [5 users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=waff) (4 if < 20 rep users are filtered out) at the time of writing that *should* match this search on user name alone. Is there another search criteria I'm missing here?
- The notice "Please note that you can only add users that have already visited this chat" doesn't seem to apply (this was on a new chat room with no messages). Come to think of it, this may explain the previous point -- are these the only users out of the five who have visited chat? If so, maybe the message can be tweaked slightly (i.e., remove the word 'this') to make sense in this context.

Comment: "this chat" is supposed to mean "the chat application on this domain," but I guess it is a little vague. The search results definitely seem weird though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the search did indeed match on the "About me" text as well -- but since there's really no use case for that, we've removed it; so from now on, it only matches on the user name.

We have also clarified the message; it now says "... that have already visited chat.meta.stackoverflow.com." (or whatever is applicable).

Comment: Excellent. Could you please clarify about the other users not showing up in the search?

Comment: @JonSeigel: Oh sorry, I thought that was clear -- it's exactly what you suspected in the last point. The other users have never visited chat.meta.