# Chat: can I grant write access to a unregistered user?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, unregistered-users

Following this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927475/should-jenkins-aka-hudson-be-installed-on-the-actual-build-server), I am trying to invite a new user (rep < 20) to a chat room
(a bit in the spirit of my [previous question about chat invitation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59716/will-there-be-an-invitation-per-so-question-feature-for-the-chat)).

I have created the [Jenkins room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/784/jenkins?tab=access) and tried to grant access to [SO user Mavig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743877/mavig) through the ["Chat room access control" interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85749/chat-room-access-control-searching-by-user-name-can-give-unexpected-results).
Neither his name nor its id or url are working though: it always triggers a
"**Oops! Something Bad Happened!**"

Is this because Mavig is a relatively new user (5 days) and "[unregistered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/unregistered-user)"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lolcat came from a problem with the Stack Overflow API; this should be fixed now.

Users with less then 20 reputation cannot talk in chat unless a *moderator* gives them access (I've done that [temporarily] in this case). We're still looking at ways to [allow high-rep users to create temporary passes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82738/allow-temporary-guest-accounts-in-chat), but that's not in yet.

Registered or unregistered doesn't matter though – it's purely reputation-based.

Comment: Thank you for the temporary pass! The meta question you are referring to would be a step toward solving http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59716/will-there-be-an-invitation-per-so-question-feature-for-the-chat, but a true "one-step" invitation system (for a low rep user, limited to one specific room) would be nice, in order to quickly switch to loads of comments to an interactive session.